# Direction rtl средствами php

Tags: php

Нужно вывести из базы текст, а точнее адрес электронной почты, в html-код справа налево. Хранить в базе адрес, читаемый справа налево как-то неудобно. Необходимо для защиты от спам-ботов (одолели). Вывести адрес справа налево, а потом его изменить с помощью `CSS - direction:ltr` на чтение слева направо. Есть какой-то метод?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте так

```
echo strrev($url);
```

Comment: спасибо большое! То, что нужно!